# Getting remote JVM properties using JMX

Tags: java, jvm, environment-variables, jmx

Can anybody give me some guides on how to get the properties of a JVM after I created a JMX connection to it? I need to get those information programmatically.
I searched for this without getting any hint.
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [JMX tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/tutorial/tutorialTOC.html) and [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/examples.html).

The properties you want can be obtained from [RuntimeMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html).

Comment: Where do you find such an example on JMX tutorial? I already read it. Regarding RuntimeMXBean, it is for the local JVM. Please correct me otherwise. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Much more concise :).

Comment: @apangin Your comment is actually not correct. See my answer below. `JMX.newMXBeanProxy` shouldn't be used here. Instead should use `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean`. I suggest you delete your comment to avoid misleading people.

Answer (score 0):

I think the smallest example should look like:

```
public class JMXSystemProperties {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9004/jmxrmi");
    JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);

    MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
    TabularDataSupport data = (TabularDataSupport) mbsc.getAttribute(new ObjectName("java.lang:type=Runtime"), "SystemProperties");
    for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : data.entrySet()) {
        CompositeDataSupport value = (CompositeDataSupport) entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + value.values());
    }
}
}
```

You can still use [jvisualvm](https://visualvm.java.net/) to see if all data are correct.

You can replace localhost and port 9004 in url to server and port which is better for you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a hint: after you connect to JMX, seems to me that there's a standard `MXBean` interface, that implements `java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean`. Related `ObjectName` should be:

`ObjectName objName = new ObjectName("java.lang:type=Runtime");`

and getting the proxy instance object is like that:

`RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(mbeanServer, objName, RuntimeMXBean.class, true);`

Maybe this will help somebody else.

N.B. If somebody can provide link to documentation that specifies the need of `RuntimeMXBean` interface for JMX capable systems, that would be welcome.

Comment: This answer is buggy, at least for me. When you call `runtimeMXBean.getSystemProperties` it returns something that isn't actually a `Map<String,String>` (it is typed as such by the compiler but its something else at runtime). I think using the `JMX.newMXBeanProxy` is to blame for that. Instead we should use `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean` to get a proxy that unpacks the data properly.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers already provided really worked for me. Some problems I had with them:

- The accepted answer is little more than a pointer to the docs, not wrong, but no real help in working out all the details.
- TabularDataSupport is a bit of PITA to unpack if you just want to get a Map of System properties. (The keys will be wrapped in lists and have to be unpacked; and the 'values' of the TabularDataSupport Map are not actually the values you want... but also still packed in a 'CompositeDataSupport' object which also has to be further unpacked.).
- Using the `JMX.newMXBeanProxy` looked promising to avoid all this unpacking. But although it compiles... at runtime, I found the result from the proxy's `getSystemProperties` isn't actually correctly unpacked at all. It is still a `TabularDataSupport` object (yes, even though it's compile-time type says it should be a `Map<String,String>`, in reality it is not).

So here is something that actually *does* work for me with all these pitfalls worked out so that it gives the system properties as just a `Map<String,String>` just like you'd probably want.

```
package example;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

public class GetJmxSystemProps {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JMXServiceURL serviceUrl =  new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi://localhost:9111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9111/jmxrmi");
        JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceUrl, null);
        MBeanServerConnection connection = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
        RuntimeMXBean proxy = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(connection, RuntimeMXBean.class);
        Map<String, String> sysprops = proxy.getSystemProperties();
        for (Entry<String, String> e : sysprops.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey()+"="+e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

To summarize: The key point here is that using `JMX.newMXBeanProxy` to obtain a bean of type `RuntimeMXBean` is buggered and does not unpack the `TabularDataSupport` object into a `Map<String,String>` correctly. This problem is avoided by using method `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean` instead.